# HttpWebRequest on Wp7 AsyncWaitHandle has System.NotSupportedException

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm having trouble with a basic HttpWebRequest in a WP7 application. As soon as I call BeginGetRequestStream, it starts to go wrong. The callback method then receives an `IAsyncResult` with no `AsyncWaitHandle`.

AsyncWaitHandle = 'ar.AsyncWaitHandle' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

I've created a sample below that produces the error. To create this I have just taken the sample pivot application and attempted to post some data to a server in the constructor of the MainViewModel.

```
   public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.google.co.uk");

        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(BeginGetRequestStreamCallBack, webRequest);
    }

    private void BeginGetRequestStreamCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) ar.AsyncState;

        Stream requestStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(ar);

        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
        {
            sw.Write("{ test: \"test\" }");
        }

        webRequest.BeginGetResponse(BeginGetResponseCallback, webRequest);
    }

    private void BeginGetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;

        WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(ar);

        Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

        string whatCameBack = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Any help would as always, be greatly appreciated.

I've looked into this a little deeper, I just can't seem to POST data using `BeginGetRequestStream`.

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.google.co.uk");

        //webRequest.Method = "POST";
        //webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        //webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(BeginGetRequestStreamCallBack, webRequest);
        webRequest.BeginGetResponse(BeginGetResponseCallback, webRequest);
    }

    private void BeginGetRequestStreamCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) ar.AsyncState;

        Stream requestStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(ar);

        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
        {
            sw.Write("{ test: \"test\" }");
        }

        webRequest.BeginGetResponse(BeginGetResponseCallback, webRequest);
    }

    private void BeginGetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;

        WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(ar);

        Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

        string whatCameBack = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
    }
```

This works okay, but it is not what I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being a naughty boy and not Closing the stream correctly.

```
using(Stream requestStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(ar))
{}
```

All is well.